# reading data generates Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, svm

I am new to MATLAB and trying to do SVM Classification.

I have dataset in txt files. First Column of data is Label and following 784 are pixels.

In binary classification, I am trying to execute following codes but get errors in `train3 = trainImagesT(trainLabels == 3,:);`

```
clc; clear all;close all;

load test00.txt;
trainLabels=test00(:,1);
trainImages=test00(:,2:end);
trainImages(1:2,:);
trainImagesT=trainImages';

train3 = trainImagesT(trainLabels == 3,:);
```

Error :

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in svm (line 15)
train3 = trainImagesT(trainLabels == 3,:);
```

How do I solve this?

Sample Data:

```
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 41 146 146 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 129 253 253 253 250 163 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 133 253 253 253 253 253 253 229 70 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 101 253 252 145 102 107 237 253 247 128 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 181 253 167 0 0 0 61 235 253 253 163 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 253 43 0 0 0 0 58 193 253 253 164 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 187 253 32 0 0 0 0 0 55 236 253 253 86 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 146 253 32 0 100 190 87 87 87 147 253 253 123 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 94 253 78 40 248 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 223 84 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 92 12 35 240 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 244 89 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 75 161 179 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 209 43 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 16 16 39 38 16 16 145 243 253 253 185 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 58 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 58 209 253 253 183 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 77 221 247 79 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 219 253 240 72 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 90 247 253 252 57 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 53 251 253 191 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 116 253 253 59 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 252 253 145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 188 253 221 158 38 0 0 0 0 111 211 246 253 253 145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 221 246 253 251 249 249 249 249 253 253 253 253 200 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 95 183 228 253 253 253 253 253 253 195 124 23 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 37 138 74 126 88 37 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What does `size(test00)` return after you've loaded it? What's the size of `trainImagesT` and `trainLabels` ? One of these is likely off (or transposed compared to your expectations).

Comment: Your code gives that error in the line `trainImages(1:2,:);` since there is no second row (there is only one row)

Comment: Thank you All, I will try and get back to you.